# Magento 2.2.0 Error : Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed

Tags: magento2

Errors on product  page :

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after'
>   is not allowed. Line: 1249
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after'
>   is not allowed. Line: 1249

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894566/magento-2-element-referencecontainer-attribute-after-the-attribute-after

Move containers so:

```
<move element="element name" destination="where you want to move" after="">
```